# Ключ PAE в boot.ini работает только в XP SP2?

Tags: загрузка, boot, windows-xp

Доброго всем дня.
Вопрос про ключ /PAE в boot.ini на XP
Этот ключ только в XP SP2 работает? В XP SP3 нет?Прописал, но ни какого эффекта нет. Даже визуального.

Answer (score 1):

ключ /PAE работает начиная с XP SP2, и в  XP SP3 тоже. В 32 битных клиентах максимум достигнешь 4Гб

Comment: Это я понимаю, но почему его пропись в boot.ini ни чего не дала?

Comment: дай скрины, дай бут, дай материнку... может у тебя на материнке ограничение стоит)